# Installed SQL Server 2016 latest GDR patch KB5021129 and my nightly integrity scans doubled in execution time (5 mins to 20-ish)

Tags: sql-server-2016

[image]I was running SQL Server 2016 SP3 with 2022/06/13 GDR.   The new GDR on 2023/02/14 came out - I applied it on May 4th.   My integrity scan SQL Agent Job went from 5 mins to 20+ overnight.   Nothing else changed.   Anyone else seen these issue?
DBs on this server here are low usage.... SQL Sentry repository and some once a year used HANA transaction simulators.   So its not like some DB doubled in size.

Comment: How does one add a screen shot to this question/post?   It help explains the issue.

Comment: I rebooted server yesterday - still same type of 22+ min runtime.

Comment: To troubleshoot, you may find [`sp_WhoIsActive`](http://whoisactive.com) helpful, which you can run while the integrity checks are running. With it, you can see what the integrity checks are waiting on and if anything is blocking them. If you find anything relevant, you should add it to your Post. Alternatively, you may find reaching out to Microsoft Support would be your best bet for an answer here.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - I use sp_whoisactive and sp_blitz* utilities from Machanic, Ozar/Darling.   But it only shows standard IO waits on the checkdb.    I ran the SQL Agent job manually during daytime hours and its 8mins 40 secs.   So I'm closing this.   I dont think its a GDR issue.   And not spending $500 for a case with MS.